# Rendered custom font cut-off

Tags: html, css, typekit

I've got a Typekit font running on my website, but it get's cut-off. Doing nothing unorthodox — just imported it.

Might be best to just show it, so check out the link below.

[Check the the last "t" in this photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACVGo.png)

Comment: please provide a link to the page or to a reduced example.

my first suggestion would be to add some padding at the right.

Comment: Are you sure the text fits? Is "t" always cut? What if you try longer word?

Comment: @AndrewDunai Happens in a lot of cases, not only the "t" in this particular word set

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide your code.

Comment: @ThomasFellinger Damn. Adding some padding actually worked. Used 3d-transforms, that might be the case